Смысл слова "ежемесячно" в фразе
Как понимать смысл фразы "ежемесячно проводить осмотр с записью в журнал..."? Имеется ввиду один раз в каждом месяце или не реже одного раза в период условно 30 календарных дней с даты последнего осмотра?

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

В дате есть месяцы - январь, февраль, март... Каждый месяц в журнале должна быть соответствующая запись. Что не ясно? Обычно это делают так: назначают срок каждый месяц не трогая крайние дни - например, в первую неделю месяца, или в последнюю неделю месяца, чтобы не было абы когда. Но если не стоит в какой день конкретно, то нужно исходить из логики здравого смысла: выбирать число которое встречается в любом месяце и стараться отмечать нужное +/- близко к этому числу.

Раз в месяц плюс-минус; за тридцать календарных дней никто не держится; ситуация не аптекарски-весовая; не "пени начисляются с 10-го числа"...
Иметь в виду - в три слова.

спасибо. буду иметь в виду!
